# Bash script doesn't work without shebang BUT the shebang results in an error message

Tags: linux, bash, centos, shebang

I am trying to run a bash script in CentOS 6.  It doesn't work without a shebang header.  When I include the shebang, however, it displays an error message!

Here's a script called test.sh.  I have it in my $HOME/bin directory.  I ran `chmod 777` on it to eliminate any permissions issues. I verified it is using Unix line endings...

```
test_var=test
echo $test_var
```

I am executing like this:

```
sh ~/bin/test.sh
```

I get the following result from that:

```
/home/myusername/bin/test.sh: line 1: ï»¿test_var=test: command not found
```

Now I add a shebang, so the script becomes:

```
#!/bin/bash
test_var=test
echo $test_var
```

When I run that, I get:

```
/home/myusername/bin/test.sh: line 1: ï»¿#!/bin/bash: No such file or directory
test
```

So it didn't have a problem assigning the variable once the shebang was added, but it doesn't like the shebang at the same time!

I checked and `/bin/bash` does in fact exist.  I tried a collection of other shebangs and got the same results.  I even tried something overtly invalid, i.e. `#!/fake/path`, and the result is the same!

The script won't run without a shebang added (no matter what it is), and yet it complains about the shebang (no matter what it is)!

Comment: What happens when you run `bash /home/myusername/bin/test.sh`?

Comment: Just tried it.  Same thing.

Comment: Also tried /bin/bash /home/myusername/bin/test.sh

Comment: Sounds like something funky with the characters in the file maybe. Try removing the first line of your file and running again, explicitly using bash from the command line invocation.

Comment: Good suggestion, but I've edited it with Notepad++ showing all characters.  There are no funky chars.

Comment: Looking into Ghislain Rouvignac answer...

Comment: Notepad++ ? Try opening it with vi on the Linux box ;) Also, did you try running it as I suggested?

Comment: Thanks quickshiftin.  Ghislain Rouvignac was right about the encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an encoding problem.

Look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8

> A text editor or web browser misinterpreting the text as ISO-8859-1 or CP1252 will display the characters ï»¿ for this.

Save your file as UTF-8 without BOM or use system editor (vi, ...)

Comment: I checked my encoding in Notepad++.  It was set to UTF-8-BOM.  I changed it to UTF-8.  That fixed it!